# How to use enum in if statement?

Tags: asp.net, if-statement, enums

I have ASP.NET application and want to use enum in if statement.

I get variable in this way:

```
string choice = (string)Session["export_choice"];
if(choice == <here goes enum>)
{
}
else
{
}
```

enum can have 2 string values only.

Comment: Make `choice` the enum type; See Enum.TryParse<> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dd991317.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is normally where I would use a `switch`:

```
myEnumType myEnumChoice;

if (Enum.TryParse(choice, out myEnumChoice))
{
    switch(myEnumChoice)
    {
        case myEnumType.FirstEnum:
            //doSomething();
            break;
        case myEnumType.SecondEnum:
            //doSomethingElse();
            break;
    }
}
else
    throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Unexpected enum value: {0}", choice));
```

Comment: I forgot to write that enum options are non-English words.

Comment: does not matter - just replace `myEnumType` with your enum type, and replace `FirstEnum` and `SecondEnum` with your non-English words.

Comment: Ok. But, what if these words are in Cyrillic?

Comment: If the enumerated type definition and values were invalid then the code would not compile at all.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
EnumChoice choice = (EnumChoice) Enum.Parse(typeof(ChumChoice), (string)Session["export_choice"] , true);
```

EnumChoice is enum type

you can use it like

```
if(choice== EnumChoice.X)
{
}
else
{
}
```